# While implementing capsule networks I am getting runtime error because of variation in channel number

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

While running CapsNet on a custom dataset which has an image of RGB 3 channels unlike MNIST dataset which has grayscale images I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2bb9162cc75d> in <module>()
      9         y = Variable(y).cuda()
     10 
---> 11         y_pred, x_reconstruction = model(x, y)
     12         loss, margin_loss, reconstruction_loss = criterion(x, y, x_reconstruction, y_pred.cuda())
     13 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight)
    348                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    349         return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 350                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    351 
    352     def forward(self, input):

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [256, 1, 9, 9], expected input[128, 3, 28, 28] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

Any clue on how to fix it or what is causing this error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add your model as well in the question. The error is caused because input to your conv 2d layer is different from what is expected.

Comment: Thank you @RajatSingh for your time. However, I got the fix now.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer by @Shai https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130331/12339371

"Your input layer self.layer1 starts with a 2d convolution nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2). This conv layer expects an input with two spatial dimensions and one channel, and outputs a tesnor with the same spatial dimensions and 16 channels.
However, your input has three channels and not one (RGB image instead of gray level image).

Make sure your net and data are in synch."