# Issue regarding channel size in DCGAN (Pytorch) for grayscale image

Tags: image, vision, dcgan

I tried to modify this example code [enter link description here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) of DCGAN for my own dataset. The exmple code is for RGB image, but my data is grayscale image. Therefore, I set the value of number of channels ‘nc’ as 1. However, when I tried running the program, i got thid error:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 64 1 4 4, expected input[128, 3, 64, 64] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead. I do know that its a problem about number of channels but I have no idea what else should I change to solve this error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size \[64, 3, 7, 7\], expected input\[3, 1, 224, 224\] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416833/runtimeerror-given-groups-1-weight-of-size-64-3-7-7-expected-input3-1)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing RGB images with `3` channels. You should pass tensor of shape `[batch, 1, width, height]` while yours is apparently `[128, 3, 64, 64]` (and should be `[128, 1, 64, 64]`).

Verify you input image shape via `print(image.shape)` attribute`

If you use `torchvision` (with `pillow` under the hood), you can use `torchvision.transforms.Grayscale()` (see [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Grayscale)). Also verify your images are indeed grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual shape of your input? My guess is that you're loading images as standard RGBs, which will load them as 3 channel images even though they're really greyscale.